# tor works when its in /usr/bin but not in /usr/sbin/

Tags: permissions, tor

I have this very strange behaviour,
I have two servers both running `Ubuntu 14.04`.
I've installed tor on both. on `machine A` tor was installed (by default) in `/usr/bin/` and works without any issues. on `machine B` tor was installed(again by default) in `/usr/sbin/` and it's giving me premission denied:

```
 is not owned by this user (debian-tor, 109) but by root (0). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
```

so I have couple of questions:

1. why `machine B` decides to install on `/usr/sbin/` (using `apt-get` installer) and `machine A` decides to install on `/usr/bin/`
2. why `machine B` gives `permission denied` where as `machine A` doesn't complain at all.

**NOTE**. on both machine the Following script is running:

```
sudo tor --RunAsDaemon 1 --CookieAuthentication 0 --HashedControlPassword "" --ControlPort $control_port --PidFile tor$i.pid --SocksPort $socks_port --DataDirectory data/tor$i
```

Update:
This is the result of running `update-alternatives –-config tor` on both machine:

It still doesn't make sense to me, but someone may know what that is all about.

A:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for tor
```

B:

```
There is only one alternative in link group tor: /usr/bin/
Nothing to configure.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/bin/ because link group tor is broken.
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/sbin/tor with a link.
```

Comment: What package sources did you use? The same on both installations?

Comment: @qbi yeah, both where of the shelf installation of ubuntu. the only difference is one has 16 process and other has 32 processes. (both 64bits)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have different packages. These are completely off-the-shelf installs, e.g., no PPAs added? Could you run `dpkg -S /usr/bin/tor` and `dpkg -S /usr/sbin/tor` and `apt-cache policy packagename` (on whatever package names you get from those `dpkg -S` calls)?